# Как пересоздать объект с агреггированными даными?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код, все работает корректно.

Нужно очень много данных агреггировать и с разными вариантами и из за этого получается очень много кода и страдает оптимизация.

Возможно ли его более короче написать или какие то другие варианты использовать?

```js
let obj = {
  2568: { plus: 10, minus: 5 },
  2584: { plus: 20, minus: 8 },
  2589: { plus: 42, minus: 9 },
  2602: { plus: 8, minus: 54 },
  // ...
};

let newObj = {};
let sum = 0;
for (let i in obj) {
  sum += obj[i].plus - obj[i].minus;
  newObj[i] = sum;
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Короче не значит быстрее и читабельнее. Если отталкиваться от вашего кода, при условии что вам надо перебирать весь объект, то тут особо уже не пооптимизируешь...